# How to Configure Kafka MirrorMaker2 for Unique Message Consumption by Multiple Consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'd like to inquire whether it's possible to configure MM2 in a manner that enables two consumers to uniquely consume messages from both the original and replicated topics.

For instance, if we have two clusters (A and B) with topicA replicated to cluster B as A.topicA, and we also have two consumers (A and B), could MM2 be configured to ensure that messages aren't duplicated when consumed by Consumer A and Consumer B?

[image]